# Edge bug? Faulty toLocaleString() results with Norwegian locale

Tags: javascript, localization, microsoft-edge

Before I try to go through the hoops of reporting this as a bug, I would like some feedback to see that this is not my own stupidity.

Edge 93 is on my machine returning en-US formatted numbers and dates with the `nb-NO` locale.

`(123456.789).toLocaleString('nb-NO')` returns `'123,456.789'`.

`(new Date(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0)).toLocaleString("nb-NO")` returns `'12/20/2012, 3:00:00 AM'`.

Chrome 94 and Firefox 92 return the correct `'123 456,789'` and `'20.12.2012, 03:00:00'`.

It's almost as if Edge doesn't recognize the BCP47 notation `nb-NO` for Norwegian Bokmål. But variations like `nb`, `no`, `nob`, and even `nn-NO`, `nn`, `nyn` (for Norwegian Nynorsk) don't return the correct result either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. I did a simple test on the content you mentioned and found that it does have such a problem, but I think you don’t need to worry about it. Because this issue has been resolved in future version of Edge, you will know if you try to test it in [Edge Canary](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/canary). Result in Edge Canary:
[image]

So I think you could look forward to the new update of Edge.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of checking the various release channels! I can see it's already fixed in Beta, so let's hope it's in Stable in a few days. 